# Which projection for Yamuna River shapefile covering Uttarakhand, Uttar Pradesh?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, india

I am looking for a common projection for a shapefile of the Yamuna River to cover Uttarakhand, Uttar Pradesh (Allahabad) as I need to calculate an area.

How do I find what projection to use?

Answer (score 3):

**Allahabad** is sharing below Projection systems:
**- Kalianpur 1880 / India zone IIa

- Kalianpur 1880 / India zone IIb**

**India projection system:**
 - Zone 0 - India and Pakistan North of 35°35'N.
 - Zone IA - India and Pakistan 28°N-35°35'N.
 - Zone IB - Unknown parts of China (Tibet).
 - Zone IIA - India 21°N-28°N & West of 82°E and Pakistan South of 28°N.
 - Zone IIB - Complete Bangladesh, India North of 21°N & East of 82°E and Myanmar (Burma) North of 21°N.
 - Zone IIIA - India 15°N-21°N.
 - Zone IIIB - Myanmar (Burma) 15°N-21°N.
 - Zone IVA - India South of 15°N.
 - Zone IVB - Myanmar (Burma) South of 15°N.

[image]

**Reference:**
**India Projection System:**
https://deeppradhan.heliohost.org/gis/indian-grid/#projection

**Spatial Reference:**
http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/?search=India+zone&srtext=Search

**ArcGIS Grid Map:**
https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=74c182a051a54986a057e10325003b0f